# GNU/Lunux архивировать файлы в директории, которые больше 5мб

Tags: linux, bash, unix, freebsd

Как в домашней директории home/[user] поместить в архив tgz все фалы, которые больше 5мб. Нужно обойти все папки и все вложения в директории [user].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я думаю, вам подойдёт нечто вроде:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Архивируем все файлы рекурсивно в текущей директории,
# размер которых превышает 5М

find . -size +5M > FileList.txt
tar --files-from FileList.txt -cvzf archive.tar.gz
```

или в одну строчку:

```
find . -size +5M ! -name archive.tar.gz | tar --files-from=- -cvzf archive.tar.gz
```

Comment: Раз `find` то почему не `… -exec tar -cvzf archive.tar.gz {} +` ?

Comment: потому что exec на каждый файл отдельно